# How do I get the element type of a collection passed in a method?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Suppose I have some method that accepts a `List<?>`

```java
public void method(List<?> list) {
    // some logic
}
```

How can I get the element type in runtime? Is it possible?

I found these suggestions (here on SO):

1. `((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]` (doesn't work, `List` is an interface and doesn't have a superclass)

```java
// ChatGPT's work

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();

        Type stringType = getListElementType(stringList);
        Type integerType = getListElementType(integerList);

        System.out.println("String List Element Type: " + stringType.getTypeName());
        System.out.println("Integer List Element Type: " + integerType.getTypeName());
    }

    private static Type getListElementType(List<?> list) {
        Type genericType = list.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();

        if (genericType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) genericType;
            return parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to determine list element type.");
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
String List Element Type: E
Integer List Element Type: E
```

2. Storing a corresponding class as a field during creation of a generic class instance (doesn't work, `List` is read-only, and it can't have any instance fields anyway since it's an interface)

```java
/*
 from jqno's answer to "How can I learn actual type argument of an generic class?"
 Henning in his answer to "Get generic type of class at runtime" suggested a similar trick
*/

class ParameterizedClass<T> {
    private Class<T> type;

    /** Factory method */
    public static <T> ParameterizedClass<T> of(Class<T> type) {
        return new ParameterizedClass<T>(type);
    }

    /** Private constructor; use the factory method instead */
    private ParameterizedClass(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    // Do something useful with type
}
```

3. The [TypeTools library](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools). I still need some supertype

> The TypeResolver class provides some of the following methods:
>
> `Type reify(Type type, Class<S> context)`
>
> Returns a fully reified type using type variable information from the context.
>
> `Type reify(Type genericType)`
>
> Returns a fully reified genericType using information from the generic declaration.
>
> `Class<?>[] resolveRawArguments(Class<T> type, Class<S> subType)`
>
> Resolves the raw arguments for a type using type variable information from a subType.
>
> `Class<?> resolveRawArgument(Class<T> type, Class<S> subType)`
>
> Resolves the raw argument for a type using type variable information from a subType.
>
> `Type resolveGenericType(Class<?> type, Type subType)`
>
> Resolves the generic type using type variable information from a subType.
>
> `Class<?> resolveRawClass(Type genericType, Class<?> subType)`
>
> Resolves the raw class for a genericType using type variable information from a subType.

Comment: Java generics are not reifiable, they're erased at runtime.  You might not be able to do this.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html

Comment: What Scary Wombat means is, if the list only contains `Dog`, then could you say the type is `List<Dog>`?  Remember that the type `List<Animal>` could still contain only `Dog`s, so that's the case he's asking about.

Comment: There is no way to do it.  However… an alternative that *does* work is using `Object[]` instead of `List<?>` as your argument type.

Comment: Where's Scary Wombat's comment? Where did it go? What he suggested was, perhaps, the best way to do it. Just look at the type of the first element. If it's empty, my logic doesn't have to take place anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I get the element type in runtime? Is it possible?

No.

Generics are a figment of the compiler's imagination. They are a tool to link places where types are used, to tell the compiler: These types need to be the same - inject casts to make it work. If you can prove types don't line up, generate compilation errors. **Then get rid of it all**.

The only thing that remains are generics **in signatures**, but what remains is the *exact* thing you wrote in the source code. Not the actual type. In other words, given:

```
public class MyExample<E> {
  public void addAll(Collection<E> element) {
    List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
    check(x);
  }

  public void check(Object o) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The generics of the `x` variable are **completely gone**. There is **nothing** `check` can do to recover that it's a `String`. The memory footprint of a `new ArrayList<String>()` and a `new ArrayList<Integer>()` is **100% identical** - it's not just 'there is no API to get this info', it's a more stringent: It is *impossible*.

You *can* get generics out for the type decl itself as well as with the `element` parameter of the `addAll` method - but you get literally the letter `E`. Which is useless.

So, to repeat: **No. Not possible**.

What TypeTools does, is abuse how signatures survive and combine that with the realization that where:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The generics part is just completely eliminated, with:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {};
```

It's not. This is because of a whole lot of hackery:

- ArrayList is not final. had it been, the above wouldn't have compiled.
- The above is almost the same as the first snippet, but in meaning, completely different: That is declaring an entirely new class with an anonymous name, defined as `extends ArrayList<String>`, and with class body `{}` (as in, it does not add anything). What a class extends is 'signature' and thus **not erased**, and thus, at runtime you can recover this stuff.

However, because it introduces a whole heap of caveats, and generics is literal, this isn't a good idea. For example, if I write:

```
public <E> createList() {
  return new ArrayList<E>() {}
}
```

That works completely fine and can be called with e.g.: `List<String> myList = ClassThatIsIn.<String>createList();` - and nevertheless, the only thing SuperTypeTokens / typetools / other libraries of that sort can ever get back out at runtime is `E` - literally. The letter E. Not `String` - that is impossible, as that's completely erased.

Hence, your super type tokens come with a manual and a long list of caveats. More generally then it's not a good idea to do this to any type other than one designed to carry this sort of info and nothing else - a super type token. A type that does nothing, all that it is meant for is for you to write `SuperTypeToken<List<String>> myTokenRepresentingListOfStrings = new SuperTypeToken<List<String>>() {}`.

This weird hackery can be useful if you have a need to convey things that generics can capture (i.e. not *just* a type, but any generics on that, as well. a `Map<String, List<? extends Number>>` for example - not just `Map`, no, that whole thing - `java.lang.Class` cannot represent that). Not to write a method that can ascertain what the generics are.

There are no workarounds. Going back to your initial question, given:

```
public void method(List<?> list) {
    // some logic
}
```

The answer is **no**. A whole heap of blogposts and articles beat around the bush and suggests ways to get to yes, but they're all incorrect. There is no way to do it. Period. super type tokens / typetools is something quite different. There is no way to use such tools to make that a 'yes'.

Comment: Thank you! It's just that sometimes you can retrieve that information about "actual types" at runtime, sometimes you can't. I don't fully understand where it retains and where it doesn't

Comment: I said it. The stuff that is in your source files _and_ in a signature, is recoverable. Everything else is not.